# Filter dataframe timeseries index by a specific time, and create a new column with 1 (if a match), or 0 (if no match)?

Tags: pandas, filter, time-series

#### Starting Dataframe

```
                         open
timestamp                    
2018-08-13 13:00:00   6401.41
2018-08-13 14:00:00   6410.00
2018-08-13 15:00:00   6258.07
2018-08-13 16:00:00   6283.50
2018-08-13 17:00:00   6246.00
```

I would like filter the timestamp index using a specific time of 15:00:00 and add a new column called 'sigbar' that has a 1 if the timestamp row is 15:00:00 or a 0 if not. Like this.

#### Expected Dataframe

```
                         open  sigbar
timestamp                            
2018-08-13 13:00:00   6401.41       0
2018-08-13 14:00:00   6410.00       0
2018-08-13 15:00:00   6258.07       1
2018-08-13 16:00:00   6283.50       0
2018-08-13 17:00:00   6246.00       0
```

#### Current code works but takes a lot of steps and feels messy.

```
# create new column 'sigbar' from index
df['sigbar'] = df.index

# fill 'sigbar' with NaT if no match
df['sigbar'] = df['sigbar'].at_time('15:00:00', axis=0)

# change dtype to int
df['sigbar'] = df['sigbar'].values.astype(int)  

# if not zero insert 1
df['sigbar'] = (df.sigbar != 0 ) * 1
```

Is there a more concise Pythonic way of achieving the same outcome, I feel like I'm referencing df['sigbar'] too many times than should be necessary? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {
    'timestamp': ['2018-08-13 13:00:00', '2018-08-13 14:00:00', '2018-08-13 15:00:00',
                  '2018-08-13 16:00:00', '2018-08-13 17:00:00'],
    'open': [6401.41, 6410.00, 6258.07, 6283.50, 6246.00]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

df['sigbar'] = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: 1 if x.time() == datetime.time(15, 0) else 0)

print(df)
```